# How do I include a jquery slider in my php template

Tags: php, jquery, templates, customization, nivo-slider

I'm pretty new to php language. I bought a template in php but I don't know how to include a jquery slider into the index page. Can anybody please help me on that? Also, after that, I want to customize the php template a little. How much php knowledge do I need?

Comment: What's your template engine ?

Comment: Well maybe you should show us part of your template.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the PHP template works. Look around the template files and try to find the needed HTML.. Then try and put your JQuery slider there. If you use an IDE such as netbeans, import the whole project, and do a find for some excerpt (which you get from the website's homepage source in a browser) on all the files.